# Sql server 2008 join query in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Please help. I have the below SQL code and it keeps getting errors:

```
create view vwUpcoming
as 
    Select a.Auction_ID, b.item_name, b.Item_Description, 
        b.Item_value, a.Expected_Start_time
    from  Auction_schedule a 
    join Item b 
        on Auction.Item_ID= Item.Item_ID 
    where a.Expected_Start_Time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The error message is:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "Item.Item_ID" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "Auction.Item_ID" could not be bound.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong aliases on this line:

```
on Auction.Item_ID= Item.Item_ID
```

You have called these tables either `a` or `b` so you need to reference those names, change the line to this:

```
on a.Item_ID= b.Item_ID
```

So your full query will be:

```
create view vwUpcoming
as 
    Select a.Auction_ID, b.item_name, b.Item_Description, 
        b.Item_value, a.Expected_Start_time
    from  Auction_schedule a
    join Item b 
        on a.Item_ID= b.Item_ID 
    where a.Expected_Start_Time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Whenever you use an alias in the FROM, you have to continue using that same alias everywhere within the query.

Comment: @user1656779 glad it worked, be sure to accept an answer via the checkmark on the left if it was helpful so future visitors can reference it.